# Are there any types of function where, a function of four variables can be expressed in terms of functions of two variables?

Tags: functions

If I have a function f(a,b,c,d) are there any types of function where it can always be equated by three functions of two variables?

Can functions g, h, j be found such that?

f(a,b,c,d) = j(g(a,b), h(c,d))

Comment: $f(a,b,c,d) = abcd, j(x,y) = xy, g(a,b)=ab, h(c,d) = cd.$
Then $f(a,b,c,d) = j(g(a,b), h(c,d)).$ Is there a specific function you are interested in?

Comment: Is there a specific function I am interested in - Not at this stage.
My rational for asking the question is, If I have a way of computing ANY function of two variables, what are the sorts of function of four variables if any, could be tackled in only twice the time.

Comment: I think I could always resort to doing g1(a,b) g2(a,c) g3(a,d) h1(b,c) h2(b,d) j(c,d) and combining these i.e. C(4,2) 6 times a pair function. But going to larger numbers of variables means C(n, 2), where as a hierarchy of pair functions has some attractions but I am concerned that one could not express as pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you asking for which $f: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R$ there exist three functiong $j, g, h: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(a, b, c, d) = j(g(a, b), h(c, d))$ without any restrictions on $j, g, h$, then the answer is "for any of them".

Let $g$ be any bijection $\mathbb R^2 \leftrightarrow \mathbb R$, s.t. $g_1(g(x, y)) = x$ and $g_2(g(x, y)) = y$, let $h = g$, and let $j(x, y) = f\Big(g_1(x), g_2(x), h_1(y), h_2(y)\Big)$.

Then $$j(g(a, b), h(c, d)) = f\Big(g_1(g(a, b)), g_2(g(a, b)), h_1(h(c, d)), h_2(h(c, d))\Big) = f(a, b, c, d)$$